# How To Have Opacity Affect Materials Using Blending Modes Other Than Just "Additive Blending"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a project in Three.js and have run into a roadblock regarding the use of both opacity and a blending mode on the same material. In my testing, I found that except for "AdditiveBlending" and "NormalBlending," changing the opacity of the material does not have any affect when a blending mode is applied.

**My question is: How can I have all of the blending modes, including custom ones, behave the same way "AdditiveBlending" and "NormalBlending" does? That is, be able to visibly adjust the opacity of the material when any blending mode is applied.**

I've already tried adjusting the source and destination factors, but they did not seem to have any effect. I also tried setting the blendSrcAlpha and blendDstAlpha to the opacity of the material, but this did not seem to have any effect either.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/CustomBlendingEquations

I included a portion the code I've written if you find it helpful.

```
let opacity = layers[l]["layer"]["opacity"]/100;
this[layerMaterial].opacity = opacity;
let blendMode = layers[l]["layer"]["blendMode"];
setBlendingMode(blendMode,this[layerMaterial],opacity);

let blendingModes = ["Normal","Lightest","Darkest","Add","Subtract","Reverse Subtract","Multiply"];
function setBlendingMode(blendMode,material,opacity){

    if (["Normal","Add","Subtract","Multiply"].includes(blendMode)){
        if(blendMode === "Normal"){ blendMode = "NormalBlending"}
        if(blendMode === "Add"){ blendMode = "AdditiveBlending"}
        if(blendMode === "Subtract"){ blendMode = "SubtractiveBlending" }
        if(blendMode === "Multiply"){ blendMode = "MultiplyBlending" }

        material.blending = THREE[ blendMode ];
    }

    else{
        material.blending = THREE[ "CustomBlending" ];

//      These do not seem to have any effect
        material.blendSrc = THREE.OneFactor;
        material.blendDst = THREE.DstAlphaFactor;

        if(blendMode === "Lightest"){
            material.blendEquation = THREE.MaxEquation;
        }
        if(blendMode === "Darkest"){
            material.blendEquation = THREE.MinEquation;
        }
        if(blendMode === "Reverse Subtract"){
            material.blendEquation = THREE.ReverseSubtractEquation;
        }
    } 

//    I commented this out because it didn't seem to have any effect either.
//    material.blendSrcAlpha = opacity;
//    material.blendDstAlpha = opacity;
}
```

This is my first time using stack overflow. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: Great first post, it's clear what you're asking and you have a nicely formatted code sample. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: @Thomas Leamon. I have the same problem, after 6 months later. Did you solve it? I also have problems with Fog because material is not affected by Fog if it's different blending

Comment: @Cihad Turhan unfortunately I haven't solved this problem yet.

Comment: @ThomasLeamon I think this is a limitation of WebGL as blending is managed by native OpenGL. I come up with a solution by placing a plane with background color over it and setting the plane opacity.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about your solution or post an example? I would really appreciate it